# Moving data to tab-delimited file python

Tags: python

I need to move these three lists of data to a tab-delimited text file. I only know how to print them consecutively (as I have done below).

```
import requests
import datetime as dt
import xmltodict
url='http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=47.6062&lon=-122.3321&FcstType=digitalDWML'
r = requests.get(url)

with open('KBFI_2.txt','wb') as outfile:
    result = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
    pop = result['dwml']['data']['parameters']['probability-of-precipitation']['value']
    pop = '\n'.join(pop)
    hqpf = result['dwml']['data']['parameters']['hourly-qpf']['value']
    hqpf = '\n'.join(hqpf)
    d = result['dwml']['data']['time-layout']['start-valid-time']
    for dte in d:
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(dte.rsplit("-",1)[0],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        print >>outfile, date
    print >>outfile, pop
    print >>outfile, hqpf
    outfile.close()
```

I'm sure this is a really easy fix, but I'm a newbie so I'm lost. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to ``outfile.close()``, as that is handled automatically by the ``with`` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to know how to combine things into multiple lines in one string (`'\n'.join`); to make lines tab-delimited, use `'\t'.join` for each line.

The other piece is to take your 3 lists and turn them into a list of triplets, so that you can use `join` to make each triplet into a tab-delimited line.  Something like this:

```
for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print >>outfile, "\t".join([a,b,c])
```

Finally, you can make a list of your dates using:

```
[dt.datetime.strptime(x.rsplit("-",1)[0],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") for x in dte]
```

Comment: Isn't this just how you make one list tab delimited? I need to print my three lists so I have a column of dates, a column of 'pop' and a column of 'hqpf'. I'm not sure how to do this with `'\t'.join`

Comment: This does not work, I get the error `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration`. I think this is happening because the value of 'date' changes when it exits its loop. Also, if I just complete your answer using 'pop' and 'hqpf', the data looks all funky in the output file. If you would like to see for yourself, you should be able to run my code because my xml doc is online.

Comment: They have to be *lists*: don't `join` `pop` or `hqpf` (that gets done in the zip loop), and collect your `date`s into a list.  And tab-separated files are allowed to look "funky".

Comment: Oh I see. I can make it work with `pop` and `hqpf` now. However, I'm having trouble converting `date` to a list. When I ask Python what `Type` it is, it gives me `<type 'type'>` and I'm not sure how to work with this. Can you shed a little light on it?